# Display object rank count in views with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

I have a page where I am displaying a list of movie. The movies are voted on by users and are in order of vote count. I'm also using pagination, so they are split every 15 movies. I need to put just a basic rank field under each movie.

Movie Name
rank #1

Movie Name
rank #2

Movie Name 
rank #3

I can't think of the best way to do this. I tried to use each with index and just display the index, however the pagination breaks this. And the count starts new every time the pagination is moved to the next group.

Does anyone have any ideas of how I might accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Sorry for not posting code in the first place. I scrapped the each with index idea as it wasn't working the way I expected. I moved to making a rank method on the movie class which still is producing an odd outcome.

** movie.rb

def rank
    Movie.all.order(vote_count: :desc)
  end

** index.html.erb

<%= @movie.rank %>

When I call this it adds a rank, but if 2 movies have the same amount of votes the ranks are still out of order.

Also I apologize for my poor stack overflow etiquette. I will review the guidelines, and do better in the future.

Comment: Share your model code and relation.

Comment: so you might give us some feedback? how about my post or shared code?

Comment: You may want to **read whathaveyoutried.com & show some respect to the StackOverflow Community**, which strongly encourages to post high quality questions, altogether with a **MCVE ( a Minimum-Complete-Verifiable-Example of code ) showing what-you-have-tried so far**. You may want to update your post, so as to meet this minimum reasonable level of quality & to show your will to respect other StackOverflow contributing members. They are professionals who love to answer good questions on MCVE-related issues. **Enjoy being StackOverflow Contributing Member & do support this Community Netiquette**

Answer (score 2):

controller:

```
def index
  @movies = Movie.order("vote_count DESC").paginate(....)
end
```

view:

```
-@movies.each_with_index do |movie, i|
  =movie.name
  %span Ranked Number #{@page-1 * per_page + i}
```

**Explanation**
Inside the Controller you paginate your collection with the page parameter (or default 1). The paginate plugin is adding a Limit to your SQL-Query. Lets say you have 100 Results and you just need page 5 (assuming each page is 10 entries), then you need just 10 entries, starting at number 40. 
in SQL that looks `LIMIT 40, 10`.

If you have your set, you go into the view and render them. The rank is calculated with Page-1 * Per_Page + current_index. Current index is starting with 0 and ends with n-1.

Lets assume you go with 40, so page is 5. That means `(5-1) * 10` is the offset, in this case 40. Then its adding the index, 0,1,2 so its coming 40, 41, 42, 43....

hope that helps

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful. I appreciate you taking the time to look over my question.

Comment: if a answer was helpful, than please mark it as "correct answer". in that case the answer will be on top and marked with an green arrow. thats the way, how stackoverflow is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a scope for count the vote.

Something like:

```
Vote.count # SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM "votes"
Movie.vote.count # SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM "votes" WHERE ....
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!